# No request parameters received in "local payments" real-time updates callback

Tags: facebook, payment, real-time-updates

I'm implementing the new "local payments", and have subscribed to real-time updates for "actions" on "payments".

My callback URL is pinged OK when a payment is made, however it has no request parameters set at all (neither POST nor GET) - it doesn't even contain the "verify token"!

(Note: I do receive the request parameters when first setting up the subscription ("hub challenge" etc) but once it is live and being notified about payments, no request parameters come through at all.

Anyone else get this problem or know how to fix it?

Thanks!

[UPDATE: SOLVED!]

Figured this out - I was expecting the values to be sent as HTTP request parameters, but they are actually sent json-encoded in the body, as documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

Comment: At one of those points where you consider hanging up your mouse and keyboard and taking up a career in anything but development I found your post, and for that I had to thank you more than just an upvote